# How to get the inializers of global variables with LLVM API

Tags: c++, c, linux, llvm, x86-64

I'm writing an LLVM pass which works on the LLVM IR code. A part of the objective is to read the initial values of global variables, where global variables could be of any type, from basic types to structs and classes. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I would ask such questions on LLVM mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you invoke `getInitializer` on a `GlobalVariable` instance you get the initializer, of type `Constant` (though make sure you call `hasInitializer` or one of its sister methods first, to verify there's an initializer at all). Also IIRC global variables and constant are implemented as the same thing, so use `isConstant` to filter out the constants if you don't want them.

Of course, a `Constant` is the abstract base class; the actual type will be one of its children, which you can see in the [diagram presented on the documentation page](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Constant.html). You can query and get the actual constant type in the usual way, via `isa` / `cast` / `dyn_cast`, or you can use `getType` on it (a constant is a `Value` after all) and work from there.

Finally, to get all the global variables from a `Module` use either the `global_begin`/`global_end` iterators, or just use `getGlobalList` on it (it has its own iterator).

Comment: Yes, I already found out how to iterate global variables and the getInitializer, hasInitializer and Constant thing, now I'm seeing how to deal with structs. Anyway, your answer is good, so +1 :)!

Comment: @MetallicPriest you'll just have to dig in more and more. A `ConstantStruct`, for example, has its values (all constants as well, of course) stored as operands.

Comment: Yes, I already got to the ConstantStruct point. This LLVM framework and its documentation is amazing!